# Filtering disabled on results in Snowflake Web UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using a snowflake db and in order to test some queries, i am running the web ui client.

Any idea why sometimes, the filtering in the ui is disabled ?

I hover over it, and it just does not allow me to filter (shows up as a greyed out / disabled option).

On some queries it works, some it doesn't.

Not exactly sure why it would work on certain queries but not others, considering both have very similar structure and both return results.

Any tips on what i might be doing wrong would help quite a bit. :)

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce. Does this happen consistently? Or sometimes for the same query? Can you share the queries?

Comment: It is systematic on certain queries. 
The query is a complex query where i build a table, then i simply do a `SELECT * FROM mytable`. I can definitely see results on there, just not able to filter through.

I am able to see the filter option work sometimes and sometimes not, depending on the query. I was thinking the quantity of results might be to blame maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this behavior is based on the size of the data displayed (rows*column).

For example, this query allows me to filter results (1x12288):

```sql
select seq4()
  from table(generator(rowcount => 12288)) v 
  order by 1;
```

But this one doesn't (1x12289):

```sql
select seq4()
  from table(generator(rowcount => 12289)) v 
  order by 1;
```

This one does (2x8192):

```sql
select seq4(), seq4()
  from table(generator(rowcount => 8192)) v 
  order by 1;
```

But this one doesn't (2x8193):

```sql
select seq4(), seq4()
  from table(generator(rowcount => 8193)) v 
  order by 1;
```

As a suggestion, consider migrating to the newer [Snowsight](https://app.snowflake.com/) console, as its web filtering abilities are much better:

[image]

Comment: Just upvoted your answer. Thanks a lot for the insight and proposing an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely based on the row size that is returned in your query.  Filter result... option is typically used for very small amounts of data being returned.  I'd recommend including the filter in your SQL statement instead.  It'll save you time and money.

I believe the reason for this limitation is that UI only actually returns a certain amount of bytes of data, and then caches the rest.  The filter result option only works against the data that was initially returned.

Comment: Just upvoted your answer. Thanks a lot for the pointers.